# bind9 service do not starts

Tags: bind

I have configured bind9. Only the named.conf.options file.
I wanted to sudo sytemctl start named.service. It was not working.
This is the output I get. I have already tried to search for the solution in many places.
Any idea?

```
named.service - BIND Domain Name Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Wed 2022-12-07 00:39:55 GMT; 32ms ago
       Docs: man:named(8)
Cntrl PID: 50934 (named)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4619)
     Memory: 1.9M
        CPU: 17ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/named.service
             \u2514\u250050934 /usr/sbin/named -u bind

Dec 07 00:39:55 xxxx-Standard-PC-Q35-ICH9-2009 systemd[1]: Starting BIND Domain Name Server...
```

Comment: What do you get for `sudo systemctl status named.service` ?

Comment: \u25cf named.service - BIND Domain Name Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Wed 2022-12-07 00:39:55 GMT; 32ms ago
       Docs: man:named(8)
Cntrl PID: 50934 (named)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4619)
     Memory: 1.9M
        CPU: 17ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/named.service
             \u2514\u250050934 /usr/sbin/named -u bind

Dec 07 00:39:55 xxxx-Standard-PC-Q35-ICH9-2009 systemd[1]: Starting BIND Domain Name Server...
 As you can see.

Comment: bind9 does not work with only a `named.conf.options` file. you need zone files. Refer to [the Ubuntu serverguide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-domain-name-service-dns).

Comment: Is it the reason why the service is not starting? It should be starting anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check bind configuration:

```
named-checkconf /etc/named.conf
```

Check Bind Zone File

```
named-checkzone demotecadmin.net /var/named/demotecadmin.net.db
```

Comment: The problem was a syntax error in /etc/bind/named.conf.options file. Thanks for help.